# Django force redirect to home page

Tags: javascript, django, redirect

this is easiest to explain with an example. I have an HTML button, when it is clicked it is supposed to change a status-field in the database. After the status-field is changed, the user is supposed to be redirected back to home.

Below is the HTML-button that calls a Javascript function:

```
{% for group in groups %}
       <button id="approve-btn" onclick="approvePendingGroup({{ group.pk 
}})">Approve</button>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the Javascript-function:

```
function approvePendingGroup(id) {
    window.location.href = "/result/approve/" + id;
}
```

The Javascript-function calls the following URL, which calls a method in views.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^result/approve/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.approve_group, name 
    ='approve_group'),
]
```

Here is the views-method that is supposed to redirect back to home:

```
@csrf_exempt
def approve_group(request, pk):
    group = Group.objects.get(pk=pk)
    group.status = Status.approved
    group.save()
    return reverse('home')
```

Unfortunately, this does not lead to the http://127.0.0.1:8000/home page
It takes me to the: http://127.0.0.1:8000/result/approve/1/home page instead. It just appends "home" to the previous URL.

How can I force this method to redirect directly to home, and not just append it at the end of http://127.0.0.1:8000/result/approve/1/?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

@csrf_exempt
def approve_group(request, pk):
    ...
    # your code
    ...
    return redirect("/home/")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I already tried that, but it did the same thing. I will try again now in another Browser :)

Comment: Please try, this is working fine at my side. I hope it works for you too.

Comment: Thank you! I tried it now, and it gives a new error, at least. It is the NoReverseMatch saying "home" is not a valid view or function pattern name. Strange because the project has:  url(r'^home/$', views.home, name='home')

Comment: are you sure that you are using same view that I have suggested, because here I am not using `return reverse('home')` so I don't think this error will occur. please check your views module has home view. and I have check your URL, it correct.

Comment: Thank you! It actually worked! Unfortunately it only works in Microsoft Edge :) at least it works though

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

@csrf_exempt
def approve_group(request, pk):
    ...
    #return reverse('home')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! But the same thing unfortunately still happens, home is just appended at the end: 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/result/approve/1/home

Answer (score 1):

You should change your JavaScript function to this:

```
function approvePendingGroup(id) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/result/approve/" + id,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function (){
          window.location.href = '/home/'
      },
      error: function(){
          alert('Something went wrong!');
      }
    });
}
```

And in your view just return a success response:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

@csrf_exempt
def approve_group(request, pk):
    group = Group.objects.get(pk=pk)
    group.status = Status.approved
    group.save()
    return HttpResponse()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! At least that made things move forward, and gave me a new problem. Now the page is stuck on: http://127.0.0.1:8000/result/approve/1/, and does not redirect to home. 

At least it gives no errors, so that is a step forward :)

Comment: @user3257736 is the group status changing to `approved`?

Comment: also, this requires `jquery`. And can you try the updated code?

Comment: Yes, the status has been approved! :) So thank you so much for that! Should I link to jquery in the HTML-file, as a <script> maybe?

Comment: @user3257736 if it changed, it means that you already have `jquery`. Check your console and see what it says.

Comment: There was no altert given of an error, not in the console or the browser. One weird thing is also that, the approving only works in Incognito mode on Chrome now. On the usual Chrome browser nothing happens, and home is appended to the end again.